# gpg: error retrieving 'me@example.com' via WKD

Tags: gpg

I am trying to encrypt a file locally and I get an error. `me@example.com` is a placeholder for my email address, a public key exists for that in my keyring and also on key servers. My private key is located on a hardware key (Yubikey). I can decrypt previously encrypted files with no problem. Here is the error:

```
➜  ~ gpg -e -r me@example.com somefile.txt 
gpg: error retrieving 'me@example.com' via WKD: General error
gpg: me@example.com: skipped: General error
gpg: somefile.txt encryption failed: General error
```

What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

P.S. There is only one more thing that might be related. My public key is expired.

Comment: WKD is the _web key directory_. Is adding the `-vv` option providing more insight what's going wrong?

Comment: Adding `-vv` prints four more lines, three of them being `gpg: Note: signature key ... expired` and the last one `gpg: <ke_id> skipped: Unusable public key`. Apparently everything boils down to the key being expired.

Comment: Extending the key solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you figured it out on your own. Feel free to add this as an answer -- this seems a rather new combination of weird error message and actual issue.

Comment: I have to use the ID and not the email on the gpg --list-key output.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Extending key expiration date fixed the problem. The error message was misleading. However adding `-vv` as Jens Erat suggested produced some useful error messages such as `gpg: Note: signature key ... expired` and `gpg: ... skipped: Unusable public key` that helped finding the actual error.

Comment: For my future self next year: in order to extend the expiration date, stop googleing and head directly over to the Arch Linux wiki page: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Extending_expiration_date.

Comment: Alternatively, `gpg --quick-set-expire PRIMARY_FINGERPRINT TIMESTAMP` to set expire of the primary key, `gpg --quick-set-expire PRIMARY_FINGERPRINT TIMESTAMP *` to set expire of the non-revoked and not yet expired subkeys, `gpg --quick-set-expire PRIMARY_FINGERPRINT TIMESTAMP SUBKEY_FINGERPRINT...` to set expire of the specified subkeys. More on it [here](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/gnupg/gpg.1.en#quick-set-expire).

Answer (score 3):

I received a similar error when using [StackExchange/Blackbox (GitHub)](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox), which is a wrapper around GPG for encrypting files in source control. Since this is the only relevant thing I could find when searching that error from Google, I'm adding this answer for posterity. Rather than `General error` this one says `Connection timed out`, but is otherwise the same:

```
gpg: error retrieving 'me@example.com' via WKD: 
Connection timed out
gpg: me@example.com: skipped: Connection timed out
gpg: somefile.txt: encryption failed: Connection timed out
```

The issue in this case was that when [indoctrinating a new user](https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox#how-to-indoctrinate-a-new-user-into-the-system) using the `blackbox_addadmin` command, the user committed an update to the `.blackbox/blackbox-admins.txt` file, but did not commit their `pubring.kbx` file.

The solution was for the user to commit and push the uncommitted `.kbx` file

I got to this solution by adding Bash `set -x` statements to the Blackbox scripts to see what `gpg` commands were actually executing, then adding the `-vv` option as described in the answer by @mehdix

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but slightly in a different situation (and on Windows :P).

I had an SSIS package with EXEC task with a command to execute `gpg.exe`. Everything was working fine in the `cmd.exe`.
However, I had the above error when I was trying to run a job with this package in the SQL Server job.

The solution was to run the GPA program as `db_agent` user and then I saw that there was no related public key for this user. So adding key for another user helped.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer to this is there could be an expired sub-key as well. Just renew the expiration date on that one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by generating a public key for `forme@example.com`
using the command
`gpg --full-generate-key`

You can read more about generating gpg key [here](https://mikeward.net/passwords/pass-a-ridiculously-great-password-manager-intro/) --> https://mikeward.net/passwords/pass-a-ridiculously-great-password-manager-intro/