# `gpg: error retrieving "email" via WKD: No data` when trying credential storage for DockerHub login

Tags: debian, docker, gpg, password-store

I want to use the `pass` credential store for DockerHub login. Therefore, following mainly [this link](https://www.antoniojgutierrez.com/posts/2018-08-11-docker_login_password_store/)

1. I installed `pass` (`apt install pass`)
2. I installed `docker-credential-pass`, but following the instruction 4 to 7 under **How to set up credential storage** in [this other link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-setup-secure-credential-storage-for-docker/)
3. I modified the `~/.docker/config.json` file adding the key-value pair `"credsStore": "pass"`
4. Since I have a GPG ID, which I can see by means of the instruction `gpg --list-secret-keys` or also `gpg -K` (in the row next to `uid` I see `[ultimate] MY_NAME <MY_EMAIL>`), and which I use often to encrypt and decrypt some files, following again [the second link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-setup-secure-credential-storage-for-docker/) or also the point 2 in [this one](https://steinbaugh.com/posts/docker-credential-pass.html), I did `pass init MY_EMAIL`. Here I got

```
mkdir: created directory '/home/user/.password-store/'
Password store initialized for MY_EMAIL
```

So, it seems that all goes right until here, but then, when I try either `docker login` or `pass insert docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check` I get

```
gpg: error retrieving 'MY_EMAIL' via WKD: No data
gpg: MY_EMAIL: skipped: No data
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: No data
Password encryption aborted.
```

However, as I said before, I use often `gpg --output out_file.gpg --encrypt --recipient MY_EMAIL input_file` without any problem.

Further, the solution in [gpg: error retrieving 'me@example.com' via WKD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405599/gpg-error-retrieving-meexample-com-via-wkd) does not seem suitable to my issue, since when I look for my key with the `gpg` commands I mentioned above, I can see `expires: 2023-07-20]`.

So, which is now the problem and what can I do? I work on Debian 11.

Maybe the issue is related to the next claim under https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers:

```
`pass` needs to be configured for `docker-credential-pass` to work properly. It must be initialized with a `gpg2` key ID. Make sure your GPG key exists is in `gpg2` keyring as `pass` uses `gpg2` instead of the regular `gpg`.
```

What should I do if this is the problem?

I have also tried doing `pass init ID` instead of `pass init MY_EMAIL` getting the ID from `gpg2 --list-secret-keys --keyid-format=long` and the line `sec rsa3072/ID date ...`, getting a problem such as in [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226944/pass-and-gpg-no-public-key), but the solutions given there do not work too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved!**

The issue was that "my" old GPG ID belonged to my `root` user, so I needed to generate a key with my non-root `user`